# javascript document.getElementById in other frames

Tags: javascript, dom, html-frames

I have two frames and want to access an element in one frame from another:

Frame 1:

```
<div id='someId'>...</div>
```

Frame 2:

```
var div=document.getElementById('someId');

div.innerHTML='something';
```

This is somehow not functioning in Firefox so I want to be sure, can I access an element in another frame by its ID?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can refer the other frame by using

```
window.frames["framename"]
```

and then you can refer the element in the DOM by using

```
window.frames["framename"].document.getElementById ( "yourelementid" );
```

Comment: so, there is no option that browser would find first available element with desired ID no matter in which frame that reside ?

Comment: @as: `getElementByid` is restricted to looking in the `document` object of which it is a method. Bear in mind that a frame is in fact a separate `window` object, and an examination of the `window`->`document` hierarchy should make it clear why a method on one `document` cannot examine a `document` in a different `window`.

Comment: It's not wirking in chrome, `window.frames['framename'].document` has nothing inside it. I mean `windows.franes['framename'].ducumnet.getElementById(...)...` results `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementByName' of undefined` error.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, The answer from @Brian Duncan do!

Answer (score 13):

The issue may be the current frame you are in. If `window.frames['framename']` does not work, try `parent.frames['framename']` to access the top level frames.

```
if(parent.frames && parent.frames['framename']) {
   var elem = parent.frames['framename'].document.getElementById(...); 
   // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having problem with the JS version but was able to use these examples for a working jQuery version:

```
var obj = $('#yourelementid', parent.frames["framename"].document);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('frameId').contentDocument.getElementById('frameChild');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you feel like trying your luck, you can just use a numeric parameter.

`window.frames[0].document`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason

```
window.frames["framename"].document.getElementById ( "yourelementid" );
```

was not working for me.

This other method did:

```
   document.getElementById('framename').contentWindow.document.getElementById('yourelementid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use
frameId.MyElementId

Of course, when defining your frame, not enough to use "name=....", rather use "id=..." within your frame tag. E.g.:

```
    <iframe id=MyFrame> .... 
          <input id=MyElementId>
               ...

    <script>
       // do something with MyElementId
           MyFrame.MyElementId.value = "something";
```

At least, it works as of 2022 (almost 2023).

[Note that I didn't even use "name"... that's quite not necessary by these days, unless you want to use radio buttons with multiple <INPUT's that refer to the same mutually exclusive element]