# ASP - using window.opener to pass values to non parent page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp-classic, window.opener

OK here is my situation. I have an address book type page (lets call it addressbook.asp for an example), on this page new rows of addresses are added every so often, this page also has a search function that can search through an address table and narrow the view. My application also has another topframe.asp page that is the same for every page.

What I'm trying to do is implement a notification system. I want to input the address info I want and when an address record is inputted into my address table on addressbook.asp that matches I'll get a pop up notification. The tricky part is I want this notification check running regardless of what page I'm on so I will be putting that function into topframe.asp. When a match is made, topframe.asp will create a pop up window saying there is a match and it will have a link back to addressbook.asp.

What I need to happen is when this link is clicked, the user is redirected to addressbook.asp and the table showing the addresses are narrowed down by the users search criteria. So I basically need to pass in the users criteria on the redirect through the link into the search form and somehow initiate submit so I can reuse addressbook.asp's original search functionality.

I was thinking I could use window.opener approach however the page opening the pop up isnt addressbook.asp. Is there a way to use window.opener or is there another function thats similar that will allow me to pass info to a page that is not the pop up windows parent?

I think the simplified version of this is I need to be able to click my link, the link redirects to addressbook.asp, my table record is passed to the search form and basically search needs to be clicked.

Comment: or I just need to be able to click my link, redirect to my addressbook.asp page and call a specific function in that page only when this link is clicked...if that makes more sense

Comment: As long as all the frame pages are on the same domain you can pass information between them and call functions in different frames, etc. There's some useful information on http://stackoverflow.com/q/1807711/858905 about how to access other frames.