# How do you access elements inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I am trying to access an element by id="mail" inside an iframe with id="frame_Customized_error_messages" from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) page. Searching for this leads to me to all sort of different ways of getting this done. However, none of them work or is bit dated. Couple of things I tried, but did not work:

[javascript document.getElementById in other frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807711/javascript-document-getelementbyid-in-other-frames)

[Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: @AshayMandwarya The answer you linked to was referenced in my question. The solution to that answer doesn't fix my specific problem. That question was posted in the year 2009. I am pretty sure, there is a modern alternative to it.

Answer (score 1):

you can`t ... access elements from iframe.. if that would be possible then i would make a new site called facebook.boo.com and have facebook loaded in an iframe and get your inputs ... thats a serious security threat...
but if you controll the app that is loaded in the iframe and is yours... then have a look on this one:
https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299

Comment: The web page works. I am just trying to replicate the same from within the developer console.

Comment: are you on locahost?\